# Starting clamav as systemd service fails

Tags: centos7, systemd, clam

I have installed `ClamAV` in `CentOS 7.3` and have problems when starting `clamd` as a systemd service.

When I start clamd manually from the command line (`/usr/sbin/clamd -c /etc/clamd.conf`), everything goes well and I can connect using clamdscan.

> When I start clamd via systemd, (`systemctl start clamd`), clamd
>   starts and, after a few seconds, terminates with the message 'Waiting
>   for all threads to finish' in the log file.
>
> Has anyone any idea why clamd starts OK from the command line but not
>   as a service? Configuration and log files follows. Thank you.

/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd.service:

```
[Unit]
Description = clamd scanner daemon
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/clamd -c /etc/clamd.conf
PrivateTmp = true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/clamd.conf:

```
LogFile /tmp/clamd.log
LogTime true
LogVerbose true
TCPSocket 3310
TCPAddr localhost
```

logfile:

```
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> +++ Started at Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> Received 0 file descriptor(s) from systemd
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> clamd daemon 0.99.2 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64)
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> Log file size limited to 1048576 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> Reading databases from /var/lib/clamav
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> Not loading PUA signatures.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:18 2017 -> Bytecode: Security mode set to "TrustSigned".
Thu Aug 31 09:52:24 2017 -> Loaded 6303399 signatures.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> TCP: Bound to [127.0.0.1]:3310
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> TCP: Stting connection queue length to 200
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: Global size limit set to 104857600 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: File size limit set to 26214400 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: Recursion level limit set to 16.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: Files limit set to 10000.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: Core-dump limit is 0.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxEmbeddedPE limit set to 10485760 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxHTMLNormalize limit set to 10485760 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxHTMLNoTags limit set to 2097152 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxScriptNormalize limit set to 5242880 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxZipTypeRcg limit set to 1048576 bytes.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxPartitions limit set to 50.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxIconsPE limit set to 100.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: MaxRecHWP3 limit set to 16.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: PCREMatchLimit limit set to 10000.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: PCRERecMatchLimit set to 5000.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Limits: PCREMaxFileSize limit set to 26214400.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Archive support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Algorithmic detection enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Portable Executable support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> ELF support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Mail files support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> OLE2 support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> PDF support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> SWF support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> HTML support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> XMLDOCS support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> HWP3 support enabled.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Self checking every 600 seconds.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> Listening daemon: PID: 5518
Thu Aug 31 09:52:26 2017 -> MaxQueue set to: 100
Thu Aug 31 09:52:28 2017 -> Waiting for all threads to finish.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:29 2017 -> Shutting down the main socket.
Thu Aug 31 09:52:29 2017 -> --- Stopped at Thu Aug 31 09:52:29 2017
Thu Aug 31 09:52:29 2017 -> Closing the main socket
```

systemctl status clamd

```
clamd.service - clamd scanner daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-08-31 09:52:29 UTC; 42 min ago
Main PID: 5516 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 31 09:52:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started clamd scanner daemon.
Aug 31 09:52:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting clamd scanner daemon ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I messed up at the installation and missed installing, among other things, the clamav-server-systemd package.

Works alright now.